# unable to read a json file while configuration in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In config block I am setting templateURL, and I want to append version number that I will get from json file to templateURL. But I am not able to get data from json file within config block.

Using grunt to build the project and creating app.js in which I have config block and within this config block, trying to get data from json file.

Comment: code.. code.. code..

Comment: Add some code, if you want us to find what the problem is.

Comment: Config blocks can't use services such as `$http`. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.